# postgres local connection errors out

Tags: postgresql

Here is my pg_hba.conf entry.

## TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

## "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only

local   all             all                                     trust

However when I try to connect with sql, I get the following error.

sql: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "

What am I missing? This works from anywhere once I include the following line.

host    all            all             0.0.0.0/0               md5

But my intent is only local connection.

Answer (score 0):

In questions like this, its better if you clarify how are you trying to connect (more specifics) to the database.

If you just want *all* local connections to work, you could try this.

```
host all all 127.0.0.1/32 md5
```

Either way, reading the pg_hba [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) is a sure way to know how to construct the above line.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I use the following way: psql -h localhost -U postgres.

Comment: Assuming that localhost is resolving to 127.0.0.1 (which it does in most cases), the above line should work ... as in it should ask for password and allow you to login. If you don't want a password to be asked, replace md5 with "trust".

Comment: Robin, well I am using the default entry: local  all  all       trust. This is the one I am having issues with. The host entry works otherwise

Comment: See "local" entries do not have / require a host column because they don't use hostname at all (they work via sockets instead).

You could either remove -h localhost option, or add a new line starting with "host" as given in my answer above.